# Xcode (LLVM) and SQLite: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Btree'

Tags: xcode, sqlite, llvm

I'm baffled by this one.... SQLite is a separate project and part of a Workspace. When building the target, LLVM is complaining:

```
<path>/sqlite3.c:44924:24: Incomplete definition of type 'struct Btree'
```

That's at line 44924 (and 14 other places following 44924). Here's what else I am seeing:

```
7145: /* Forward declaration */
7146: typedef struct Btree Btree;
...

11378: struct Btree {
11379:   sqlite3 *db;       /* The database connection holding this btree */
11380:   BtShared *pBt;     /* Sharable content of this btree */
11381:  u8 inTrans;        /* TRANS_NONE, TRANS_READ or TRANS_WRITE */
11382:  u8 sharable;       /* True if we can share pBt with another db */
11383:  u8 locked;         /* True if db currently has pBt locked */
11384:  int wantToLock;    /* Number of nested calls to sqlite3BtreeEnter() */
11385:  int nBackup;       /* Number of backup operations reading this btree */
11386:  Btree *pNext;      /* List of other sharable Btrees from the same db */
11387:  Btree *pPrev;      /* Back pointer of the same list */
11388:#ifndef SQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE
11389:  BtLock lock;       /* Object used to lock page 1 */
11390:#endif
11391:};
...

44919: static void lockBtreeMutex(Btree *p){
44920:   assert( p->locked==0 );
44921:   assert( sqlite3_mutex_notheld(p->pBt->mutex) );
44922:   assert( sqlite3_mutex_held(p->db->mutex) );
44923: 
44924:   sqlite3_mutex_enter(p->pBt->mutex);
44925:   p->pBt->db = p->db;
44926:   p->locked = 1;
44927: }
```

I also tried renaming the struct at 11378 to `struct Btree_S` (and changed the `typedef`). Same problem.

I guess my question is, how can it be incomplete? Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking at the preprocessed source; the preprocessor can do strange things to source code.  Also, if you're asking about a compiler diagnostic, please include the complete diagnostic output.

Comment: Thanks @servn. I'm trying to clean up a reject, and I think its related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327744/xcode-4-subproject-does-not-honor-inherited. I will get the output shortly.

Comment: And what is at line 44924 in your version of `sqlite3.c`?

Comment: @CL - added the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `sqlite3.c` is compiled as C, not C++.

Comment: Thanks CL. I know how to bring up build settings, but how does one do that for a file (rather than project) in Xcode. I right click sqllite3.c and I get nothing after "Show File Inspector".

Comment: Thanks CL. The points are yours since you suffered my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.... The preprocessor macro `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1` was not defined. Why was it not defined? Because of [Xcode 4: Project does not honor $(inherited) Build Setting in Workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327744/xcode-4-project-does-not-honor-inherited-build-setting-in-workspace).

`$(inherited)` does not work in Xcode 4 as expected across projects in a parent/child relationship (despite what the IDE's tree view shows us), and what the documentation implies about `$(inherited)`.

Xcode configuration files (xcconfig) do not work as expected either. I could not get the configuration file assigned to other child projects (only the top level project).

Apple should fire their entire QA department and technical writers, and hire a new bunch of ID10Ts.